# MVC - break controller to subclass hierarchy

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I currently have a single controller (implemented using Spring mvc),  for students and teachers to upload files Controller name is FileUpoadController

I would like to break the controller functionality and extend it using:

```
 StudentFileUploadController  extends FileUpoadController      
 LecturerFileUpoadController  extends FileUpoadController
```

So FileUpoadController will be abstract and maintain the base functionality.

Current controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload") 
public class FileUpoadController
```

One solution is to make different upload mapping with two controllers

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadStudent") 
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadLecturer")
```

Is it possible any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unlikely that those method behave exactly the same besides the different mapping. But you can use delegation instead:

```
public class FileUpoadController<T> {
    public List<T> getList(){
        // returns list of T
    }
}

@Controller(value = "/uploadStudent")
public class UploadStudentController extends FileUpoadController<UploadStudent>{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/list")
    public @ResponseBody List<UploadStudent> getStudent() {
      return super.getList();
    }    
}

@Controller(value = "/uploadLecturer")
public class UploadLecturerController extends FileUpoadController<UploadLecture>{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/list")
    public @ResponseBody List<UploadLecture> getLecture() {
      return super.getList();
    }
}
```

for more details please refer this:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/799677/The-Hierarchy-of-Controller-Class-in-ASP-NET-MVC